# where does this metric come from/how is it called?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

[image: metric]

So I have this metric I'm sure I've seen somewhere before, but I need to know where it comes from, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

google is your [friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_wormhole). This is Ellis wormhole metric (it's proper-length form)